# NEST OptOut in code

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

NEST provides a way to specifically ignore a certain property:

```
[ElasticProperty(OptOut = true)]
```

This works great - except when I don't have access to decorate properties on parent classes (which exist in other libraries/frameworks and aren't accessible).

Is there a way to set this value (and other settings about these properties) in code, rather than via an attribute?

Comment: There are properties on a parent object that I cannot attribute since it's in another library, thus they throw a StackOverflow when NEST attempts to serialize them.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a proxy class for your search stuff. Will give you much more control and future proof your app. Try using [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to make this easier.

Comment: As a general rule, I implement proxy classes for my search entities to allow for scenarios such as this (adding appropriate attributes) and also because how I represent an item in the index usually does not correlate directly to other objects (classes) in my domain.